# Javascript 'this' context in recursion?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

writing a simple BST implementation in JS and I'm running into something I don't understand. Code follows:

```
var Node = function(time, value) {
  // has time and value
  this.time = time;
  this.value = value;

  this.left;
  this.right;

  // we have an insert method.
  var insert = function(time, value) {
    if (time <= this.time) {
      // go left
      if (!this.left) {
        this.left = new Node(time, value);
      } else {
        this.left.insert(time, value);
      }
    } else {
      // go right
      if (!this.right) {
        this.right = new Node(time, value);
      } else {
        this.right.insert(time, value);
      }
    }
  }

  this.insert = insert;

  // we have a find method
  var that = this;
  var find = function(time) {
    if (time === that.time) {
      // we found the node, let's return this one
      console.log("%%%" + **that.value**);
      return **that.value**;
    }

    if (time > that.time) {
      this.right.find(time); 
    } else {
      this.left.find(time); 
    }
  }

  this.find = find;
}

var a1 = new Node(3, "aad");
a1.insert(9, "bbasd");
a1.insert(5, "caadfas");
a1.insert(10, "daddaf");

console.log(a1.find(3));
console.log(a1.find(5));
console.log(a1.find(9));
console.log(a1.find(10));
```

This outputs:

```
%%aad 
aad 
%%caadfas 
undefined 
%%bbasd 
undefined 
%%daddaf 
undefined
```

Why does the console print line have the correct this.value but the returned this.value is undefined?

Thanks!

Comment: Try moving your var that = this; up above the var insert = function.....  and use that instead of this inside of the  var = insert function... block.

Comment: The lines `this.right;` and `this.left;` do absolutely nothing.

Comment: There's really no need for the `that` in the code posted here, because `.find()` is always invoked via a reference to the relevant object. Thus `this` would be a reference to the correct object to be examining.

Comment: @Pointy That's a great point, can you explain that a little more? I thought "this" in javascript is bind to the function, so within .find() the 'this' context of the outer object would be lost?

Comment: @kaid inside `.find()`, the only object you care about is the one that'll be referenced by `this`.  The value of `this` is determined by how a function is *invoked*. In your case here, `.find()` is always invoked via a reference to the object that the function examines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning the results of calling `.find()` via the "left" or "right" links. You're just calling the function and throwing the result away.

Instead:

```
if (time > that.time) {
  return this.right.find(time); 
} else {
  return this.left.find(time); 
}
```